# Maintain small gap in textinput and keyboard when textinput is focused

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

I have multiple textInputs on my screen, when textinput are in focus keyboard appears, and content move up nicely.

Currently this loook like [image]

At present this is confusing for users, it would look better if there was a little gap between textInput and Keyboard. Is there a way to do that. Thanks

NOTE: whole thing is inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`KeyboardAvoidingView`

like

```
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
  ... your UI ...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Comment: KeyboardAvoidingView doesn't work properly with scrollview